# How I can self-ground an EU Schuko plug with a grounding rod?

Tags: electrical, grounding, cord-and-plug

Because once I touch my PC case I am being zapped, as an indication of bad grounding. I thought to place some sort of temporary grounding into the socket that the computer plugs in.

What I though is to drill the concrete floor and place a grounding rod, then I would connect the plug to this grounding rod via a wire and (Once I have closed the mains first). Then my computer will be plugged into this the grounded plug.

Ι live in a ground floor without any basement just pure concrete floor.
The idea is to have plugs connected to their grounding rod isolated from the bad grounding of my old electrical installation.

Is that feasible, or I may make things worse? (That's why I am asking first)

The grounding rod will be covered with some plastic casing such as a PVC pipe with a cover and with silicone at any uncovered cable.

Well my house is rather old. Once I touch metalic surfaces on any device I fill like a small current passes by. By touching my PC's metal case sometimes I feel like some sort of current to hit me but Idk if it is too much or not. Usually by using a testing screw once I touch the metal surface of the Pc the internal lamp lights on.

Comment: Have you tried to find the problem in your PC which is causing the case to be energized?

Comment: Are you in Europe, Africa or Asia? Does your house have TN-C-S earthing (neutral and ground coming from utility as a combined PEN conductor, and hope it is good)?  Have you seen unusually high or low voltages?

Comment: Is this a laptop connected via a charger, or a desktop plugged straight to the mains? 'Zapping' as opposed to 'near-terminal-electrocution' is a vastly different issue with a charger vs direct mains.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I live in Greece and I have no idea about my house's eathing system.

Comment: @Tetsujin That happens on my PC once I touch my pc's metalic case.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It is a desktop Pc @Tetsujin

Comment: OK, then that is highy dangerous, see the answers below. [Had it been a laptop then the diagnosis could have been different].

Comment: Is it possible that the humidity is dropping (as it is here in North America) as winter approaches and that you're actually getting a _static electricity_ discharge, not a zap from mains power? My wife just kissed me good morning and we both got zapped on the lip while _neither_ of us was anywhere _near_ anything else electrical.

Comment: No because it also happend in other applianced on another room (Kichen and a Blender)

Answer (score 5):

Localized ground rods will not solve your problems.  Do not do this.

Grounding is supposed to save you from electrocution if you have an un-diagnosed problem.  You do have a problem, probably more than one, and you apparently have been electrocuted.  What you need to do now is fix the problem, not install a half-baked grounding system for one outlet.  That will achieve nothing.

Let's start with the PC.   You say it's "zapping" you.  Electrocution from 220V mains could be described as "zapping" but it's extremely painful and dangerous.  Usually, after being "zapped" this way ... you do not go on the internet to enquire about rigging up grounding rods.  You make sure it never happens again.  Not to your body, or anyone's.  You find out where 220V is being supplied to the case of your PC and you fix that.   It may not be in the PC.  If you have a faulty ground system, it may be somewhere else that's energizing your ungrounded ground system.

Which brings us to the next thing .. your "bad grounding".  Is it possible you have *two* highly dangerous, near-fatal conditions?   1) Something is energizing (some of) your ground wires and 2) Those aren't connected to ground?   Well, if you do go ahead and connect them to ground, perhaps by driving a rod through your floor ... *the best thing* that might happen is to blow your RCDs or main breaker, de-energizing your entire home ... and giving you some quiet and serenity in which you could contemplate actually fixing the two underlying problems rather than working around them!

Another possibility is that the "zapping" you feel is something different ... not actually 220V mains waiting to kill you.   Something less painful, less dangerous.  I don't know what.   You really need to investigate this, find out what is actually wrong, and fix the underlying problems.

Do you even have RCDs?  If what you are experiencing is actual 220V electrocution, which I slightly doubt (because your reaction would be more radical than to write this post) your RCDs ought to have blown.  You don't say they blew.  So either you don't have any (yet another danger) or your "zapping" is something else.

Comment: RCDs don't help with a broken PEN in a TN-C-S.  Generally taking the earth from your utility is not great.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica wouldn't OP's question include "nothing works" and his fridge etc all zappy too?  I mean ya people are quite selective in describing their problems but I think the question would be a little different.

Comment: You know how US houses can lose a neutral at the pole, and it causes neutral to wander between the two phases?  The same thing can happen with Euro 1-of-3 phases *at the neighborhood level*, with neutral wandering among the 3 phases based on relative load on each phase. Like our case, things often are still working because the voltage is good enough.  But with TN-C-S, when neutral wanders, so does "the earth pin" (NOT to be confused with proper earth) because houses don't have their own ground spikes.

Answer (score 2):

### In Euro style systems, adding ground spikes is *complicated*

What you have is one of several TN-style earths, where you allow the power company to supply your earth for you, and don't have a local earth spike at your house.

What you're talking about is a TT system, where you accept power company live and neutral, and then obtain your own earth from a local earth spike.

This is a big mess because of legacy ways that Europe does things (notably: not tying system neutral to earth spikes at every building).

John Ward does a fine job of covering the complications [here in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5OtLg6voZY).

To summarize, it's not easy to just put a ground spike into the earth and "call it good".  Interaction with water pipes, sewer and methane pipes, etc. will end up bringing the faulty netural right back to you.

However, the best type of earthing is actually when the reinforcing rod/mesh in the concrete pour is tied to the electrical earthing.  You don't do that by merely drilling a hole in the concrete, you need to dig a bit and reach the reinforcing rod, make good electrical contact with that, and then backfill with concrete (since the concrete [is absolutely necessary](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiIltPD6ej6AhUVZTABHaXaCIMQwqsBegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D65vfMUP4-i8&usg=AOvVaw0BHmR-azAgM-pSpV9MjPLj) to protect the reinforcing mesh from rusting).

So watch the video, note the complications and decide how you want to approach it.

It may also help to see if there is something basically wrong with your earth wiring or appliance connections.

Comment: Well my house is rather old. Once I touch metalic surfaces on any device I fill like a small current passes by. By touching my PC's metal case sometimes I feel like some soft of current to hit me but Idk if it is too much or not. 

Usually by using a testing screw once I touch the metal surface of the Pc the internal lamp lights on.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas The information in the above comment should be in the question.  1) It's not only your PC it's everything, and 2) It's not a full-on 240V-through-you situation because I promise your description of that would be different.  These facts would narrow down the problem.